# How to render ui from xml

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

[image]

I wanted to create my own tool for android where i will change xml and that should reflect android ui side by side likewise what android studio and eclipse does.

Can someone tell me what android studio and eclipse uses to render ui from xml as shown in screenshot.

Comment: use androidbuzz. https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/

Comment: @KDeogharkar I want to create tool where from xml i have to render ui as shown in image.

Comment: Talk about reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First off**: it is not really clear what you want to achieve so I think I should ask some questions first.

<strike>- Do you want to create an add-on for an existing IDE?</strike>

<strike>- Do you want to create an Android Application?</strike>

**- Do you want to create an IDE similar to Android Studio/ Eclipse?**

**Answer: If you want to create your own IDE then you need to implement the parsers and preview using 2D drawing. The tools AndroidStudio or Eclipse use to display the XML Views are part of the IDE. As far as I know there is no tool that will display your XML preview as they do. Follow the next instructions in order to implement that part.**

But regardless of the answer to any of the questions above, here are some directions.

1. Since you need to know what kind of content you're using, you should start with an `xml parser`. How to do that can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).
2. Next step would be to actually draw the `Views` hierarchy somewhere. For that you need a basic 2D drawing knowledge, and you can start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
3. Access the resources for different platform and draw them to your window, using processed xml information and Android specific images. You can access the Android specific resources (images) for different platform, through the AOSP [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

I hope i managed to point out some directions.

Comment: Arkde : What do you think eclipse and android studio both have implemented their own logic for rendering ui then. I think android sdk contains something tool(ex - .exe) which takes android xml as input and renders ui. To know that exact process how they are rendering ui i have posted this question

Comment: Yes i want to create my own IDE

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex thing to do:

One and only solution , Making the compiler for XML, If there are openSource  XML parser for java Use them.
If there are not any I am afraid you have to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

unity can do it for you its funny but you can do it with unity you can make android native views like button and ... in as objects in unity and load xml for adding views in right place,its so hard but possible and intresting